# Trying to run Django tests, get error loading either pysqlite2 or sqlite3?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, python-3.4, pysqlite

I am trying to run tests on a project that is not mine when i python manage.py test, I get

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading either pysqlite2 or sqlite3 modules (tried in that order): %s" % exc)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading either pysqlite2 or sqlite3 modules (tried in that order): No module named '_sqlite3'
```

I have installed the sqlite3 and pysqlite2 and all the dev-lib packages, it tells me the requirements are already satisfied. I installed them outside of the virtual env, I believe this is my problem, but I am afraid to use sudo apt-get remove because last time I used this command I deleted almost my entire Ubuntu. Any suggestions?

Comment: So currently your project is running inside Virtualenv?

Comment: @AbijithMg yes it is

Comment: Have you tried installing the modules inside of the virtual env and trying again?

Comment: I have, unfortunately not a solution @JohnMoutafis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am using Ubuntu I had installed python from the terminal, not from [source](https://www.python.org/downloads/source). The installation I did must not have included sqlite3.

Steps I took to solve issue:

Download the source file of the Python version that you need, from [source](https://www.python.org/downloads/source). Extract the folder somewhere, cd into the folder,

```
./configure
make
make install
```

fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

- Inside your virtual env:

  ```
  pip install pysqlite2
  ```

**NOTE**: sqlite3 module is included in the standard library (since Python 2.5).

EDIT: try this to install the following:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev libsqlite3
```

Comment: already tried this, i get the error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pysqlite2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pysqlite2

Comment: I think the problem is that I have to reinstall python3.4 to update these installs, but how do I do that ? I am running Ubuntu 16, if I use apt-get remove I am afraid I might delete everything that contains *python*

Comment: I have tried almost everything I could find in SO, without reinstalling python. Only because i do not know how.

Comment: With your edit, i get: E: Unable to locate package libsqlite3

Comment: Execute sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade as per new edit then try.

Comment: I still get the same error as above, unable to locate package libsqlite3 :(